# Antlr4 visitors and members

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm currently investigating ANTLR4 , and I'm struggling a bit to find information on how the visitors are used. The following page: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules and reading though the ANTLR generaged files in my little dummy project, leaves me with the following questions

- how do I access the fields of the parser in the listener? For example, if i use `@members {int mynumber = 0;}` in the grammer, how can I access this within a method of the listener implementation?
- Can anybody point me to a small example, targeted at somebody fairly new to antlr which uses visitors?

Answer (score 3):

This example by Bart Kiers really helped me: [If/else statements in ANTLR using listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners)

There's more info if you grab the example source files: https://github.com/bkiers/Mu