# How can I get output from an ANTLR 4 project?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I've just begun working with ANTLR and was trying to follow a simple example I found on SO from awhile ago: [ANTLR: Is there a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example)

I want to do a similar type of thing with my ANTLR 4 project. Does anyone know how I could do this?

I have my grammar defined and it can generate correct trees.

Essentially, I want to see the answer generated from a mathematical expression, not just a confirmation that my grammar is correct.

Please help!

Comment: This Q&A contains an example of an expression parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners

Answer (score 0):

The book goes through all this but the basic idea if you just want to calculator is to return a value from the expression rule:

`e returns [int value]
  : left=e '*' right=e {$value = $left.value * $right.value;}
  | left=e '+' right=e {$value = $left.value + $right.value;}
  | INT                {$value = $INT.int;}
  ;`