# How to describe String that contains characters with range counts under ANTLR4 lexer rules?

Tags: antlr4

There's a rule about the flight no(such as:CZ3102), which has 2 chars followed by 3-4 digits.
And its Regular Expression should be:
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3,4}.

Then how to write the lexer rule under ANTLR4?

One easy lexer rule is:
[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?

But that's not so elegant, and if the range is big, such as 1-255, it's not so easy the lexer rule.

Thanks

Comment: Behind the cover ANTLR4 uses java regex. So maybe something like [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) will work.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta Your statement could not be farther from the truth. ANTLR 4 uses a custom implementation of an NFA simulation with on-demand DFA caching. There are no references to Java's Regular Expression implementation anywhere in the ANTLR 4 runtime, much less in the lexer implementation itself.

Comment: Wow I couldn't believe it and I checked the github repo. Basically no reference to java.util.regex. Good catch! Unfortunately I could not find a reference for the ANTLR4 regex. I used to have the book but I no longer do so I can't confirm it's in there.

Comment: I guess [this](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules) is a start.

Comment: So, buddies, how to resolve my problem? or use the non-greedy mechanism:[A-Z]+?[0-9]+?

Answer (score 1):

> But that's not so elegant, and if the range is big, such as 1-255, it's not so easy the lexer rule.

Tokenize just numbers, and validate the numerical value inside parser listener or visitor.

Related links:

- https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Listeners
- [If/else statements in ANTLR using listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners)