# ANTLR: expression evaluation with custom object and method

Tags: expression, antlr

Is it possible to use ANTLR internally in a Java program and use custom classes to execute actual operations ? I would like to be able to parse simple expressions and execute custom operations for them defined in my own Java classes.

Sample expression :

(( AB1 op1 BC2) op2 BB )

AB1, BC2 and BB represent custom Java classes for example MyObj. op1 and op2 are very simple operations and could be thought as + or -

Let's say I have:

```
interface Operation {
    public MyObj operation(MyObj obj1, MyObj obj2);
}

class SomeOperation implements Operation {
    public MyObj operation(MyObj obj1, MyObj obj2) {

    };
}

class Some2Operation implements Operation {
    public MyObj operation(MyObj obj1, MyObj obj2) {

    };
}
```

SomeOperation refers to op1 and Some2Operation refers to op2.

Before evaluating the expression of course actual objects for AB1, BC2 and BB are assigned.

If there's easier/simpler way to accomplish this than using ANTLR please let me know.

EDIT: Continues here...

```
grammar MyTest;

ID: [a-z]+;

Operator_I: 'I';
Operator_U: 'U';


prog:   (expr)* #myProg;
expr:   expr op=(Operator_I | Operator_U) expr  #myExpr
    | ID    #myID
    |   '(' expr ')' #myWithPar
    ;


import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.NotNull;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;

import java.util.*;

public class EvalVisitor extends MyTestBaseVisitor<Value> {

    @Override
    public Value visitMyProg(MyTestParser.MyProgContext ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("prog:"+ctx.getText());
        return super.visitMyProg(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public Value visitMyWithPar(MyTestParser.MyWithParContext ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("par:"+ctx.getText());
        return super.visitMyWithPar(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public Value visitMyID(MyTestParser.MyIDContext ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("id:"+ctx.getText());
        return super.visitMyID(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public Value visitMyExpr(MyTestParser.MyExprContext ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("expr:"+ctx.getText());
        return super.visitMyExpr(ctx);
    }

    private Map<String, Value> memory = new HashMap<String, Value>();   
    private Map<String, Value> values = new HashMap<String, Value>();

    public EvalVisitor() {
        values.put("a", new Value(new Double(5)));
        values.put("u", new Value(new Double(9)));

    }

}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyTestLexer lexer = new MyTestLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("c:\\test.mu"));
        MyTestParser parser = new MyTestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTree tree = parser.prog();
        EvalVisitor visitor = new EvalVisitor();
        visitor.visit(tree);
    }
```

test.mu contains:

```
(aIu)U(aUu)
```

output of the program:

```
prog:(aIu)U(aUu)
expr:(aIu)U(aUu)
par:(aIu)
expr:aIu
id:a
id:u
par:(aUu)
expr:aUu
id:a
id:u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR only provides a parser for your language. An actual interpreter (evaluating your input) is up to you. You can use ANTLR's visitors to easily create an interpreter. A demo can be found in this Q&A: [If/else statements in ANTLR using listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners)

If you don't want to write the interpreter yourself, you'll need to find a library that suits your needs. See this Q&A for a list of available libraries: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Comment: Added some more data in main question area. I got basic things done quite quickly. Thanks a lot for that. Thanks!

I'm wondering about what to do in actual callback functions visitMyExpr etc. Should I save value of 'expr' in hashtable or what ?

Also is my grammar correct ? I want also to do this: ((aUb)Ic) and now it seems it will omit the last 'Ic)'  ?

Comment: @knocker_d, I've not the time right now. Instead of editing your original question (which was a short question, and I therefor answered it), I recommend asking a new question instead. Good luck!