# Skip subtree in Listener ANTLR4

Tags: listener, antlr4

Is there any Way to skip the parsing of specific block while using Listener in ANTLR4 using enter or exit method.
I have read [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners) but unable to make it work.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

By the time you're using the Listener pattern with your own Listener class, the **input is already correctly lexed and parsed**.  Therefore, the answer to your question is no.  When you're using the listener you're typically just walking the tree post-parse.

Does that mean all is lost though?  Of course not.  All you have to do is simply **not code the `Enter` or `Exit` events for those constructs you want to "ignore."** It's that easy.

As to if-else statements, I've always implemented them using the visitor pattern like this:

As to how to program an `if` statement, I'll give you a peek at they way I implement them:

```
    public override MuValue VisitIfstmt(LISBASICParser.IfstmtContext context)
    {
        LISBASICParser.Condition_blockContext[] conditions = context.condition_block();
        bool evaluatedBlock = false;
        foreach (LISBASICParser.Condition_blockContext condition in conditions)
        {
            MuValue evaluated = Visit(condition.expr());
            if (evaluated.AsBoolean())
            {
                evaluatedBlock = true;
                Visit(condition.stmt_block());
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!evaluatedBlock && context.stmt_block() != null)
        {
            Visit(context.stmt_block());
        }
        return MuValue.Void;
    }
```

Granted, this probably doesn't make much sense out of context, but rest assured it works.  To see this in its full context, please visit [Bart Kiers](https://github.com/bkiers/Mu) for an excellent example of grammar and implementation .

Comment: can we implement if-else statements by using JUST listeners?

Comment: @BreatheHacker  Please see my update answer regarding if-else.  Once I learned this pattern, I never looked back to see if it could be done using only listener.

Comment: I wanna some explanation about `ctx.expr()`. How this is working. i.e evaluating the expression and saving of value in HashMap?

Comment: No, not hashMap.  Each Visit() call eventually is resolved into a MuValue object.  This is the difference between Visitor and Listener.  Visitor can return a value of any type, in this case a MuValue object.  In Listener, you have to construct your own mechanism to store values as you traverse the tree.  That's why I chose visitor; for anything that requires something more complicated than a Stack, I use visitor.  Listener works great with Stack as the storage mechanism.

Comment: What I have learned so far is that hashMap is only used to store the ID atom and Value associated with that ID atom. Now as we have (*) on stat so while logging out the value each time when stat block is called for parsing then first of all value of n is returned then the string is printed on screen.(but what about + sign there?).Correct me if i'm wrong