# Parsing Tokens inside of Strings in Antlr4

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to get my head around how to write grammar which will first parse an input for strings, and then when strings are found, parse that string.

For example, if I had an input such as:

```
var1 = "world"
someVariable = "hello {{var1}}"
```

The result I want is for someVariable to be equal to "hello world".

Now, I understand how to write the grammar to set a variable to a string, but what I cannot figure out is how to parse that string for the mustache syntax in order to inject the value inside of var1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to do this in two steps:

- Parse the input as usual (i.e. to determine the assignments, without analyzing the contents of the strings)
- Then evaluate the assignments

  - While assigning a string to a variable, parse its contents with *another* parser (or perhaps even just with regex if the syntax is simple enough) to determine any replacements.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up implementing this functionality with regex. Out of curiosity, is having multiple parsers good practice in Antlr?

Comment: I don't know about "good practice in ANTLR", but the two are principally two different languages, one interpreting strings that the other considers just data with no inner semantics.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what ANTLR does. ANTLR can surely parse your input, and even tokenise `"hello {{var1}}"` separately<sup>1</sup>, but it does  not evaluate `var1` and substitute it. That is something you will need to do after ANTLR is done parsing<sup>2</sup>.

1. checkout the docs on lexical modes: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes
2. this Q&A shows a simple example how to evaluate something using a visitor: [If/else statements in ANTLR using listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners)

Comment: I agree with you. I suppose I could've been more specific with my question. I already have the visitor pattern built and working for utilizing variables. What I can't figure out is how to parse the contents of those strings seperately using lexical modes. The documentation is quite sparse.