# 'MyGrammarParser' object has no attribute 'startRule'

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

So, I'm trying to use Antlr4 for Python to generate Abstract Syntax Trees from my code. I'm pretty much following exactly every step described here:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md

Since I'm trying to parse Python code, I downloaded the Python grammar from here:https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3-py/Python3.g4
which I renamed as `MyGrammar`. From that step onwards, I did exactly the same things described in the link. I did `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 MyGrammar.g4` from the Terminal, and then I created the following Python script:

```
from antlr4 import *
from MyGrammarLexer import MyGrammarLexer
from MyGrammarParser import MyGrammarParser
 
def main(argv):
    input_stream = FileStream(argv[1])
    lexer = MyGrammarLexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = MyGrammarParser(stream)
    tree = parser.startRule()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

However, for some reason I'm getting `'MyGrammarParser' object has no attribute 'startRule'`.
I know this question has been asked previously here ([AttributeError: 'MuParser' object has no attribute 'startRule'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161501/attributeerror-muparser-object-has-no-attribute-startrule)), but people are recommending to use the `parse` command instead. The problem is that I'm getting the same problem (it is not recognized as an attribute). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

That means you have not defined a parser rule called `startRule` in your `MyGrammar.g4` file:

```
// File: MyGrammar.g4
grammar MyGrammar;

startRule
 : ...
 ;

...
```

> but people are recommending to use the parse command instead. The problem is that I'm getting the same problem

Then you don't have a parser rule called `parse` either.