# How to parse config file with data of different types in C++?

Tags: c++, file, parsing, types

Let's say we've got a config file with following data:

```
name=Ben
age=21
score=4.65
```

I want to parse this data and initialize custom class fields with it without defining datatype in process.

Custom class InpData:

```
class InpData {
  std::string name;
  int age;
  double score;
};
```

That is what I'd like to avoid:

```
InpData mydata;
while (std::getline(file, line) {
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  if (std::getline(iss, key, '=')) {
    if (key == "name")
       // read "Ben" to mydata.name
    else if (key == "age")
      // read "21" to mydata.age
    else if (key == "score")
      // read "4.65" to mydata.score
  }
}
```

In other words, I'd like to have something like std::map but with possibility to add data with different types.

I thought about std::variant or std::tuple, but as for me it's not what I need.
I guess, some custom container is needed.

Comment: *"without defining datatype in process..."* Simply not possible in C++. C++ is a typed language. Types are determined at compile time.

Comment: I am unsure what "*without defining datatype in process*" means. I am also unsure why you would consider using variants: surely you would not accept a configuration that says a person's `age` is `New York` or their `name` is `01/12/2023`, right? But even if for some reason, you wanted the above processed, why are you rejecting the use of `std::variant` straight away? Is it not exactly what you would need? Could you please provide some pieces of context for us to understand the goal?

Comment: While waiting for the answer to the above questions, what you are looking for is most likely a parser/lexer such as [Antlr](https://www.antlr.org/) (there are probably a few other out there but this is the one I use). You can find an example to get you started [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15614911/20143744).

Comment: You might want to take some inspiration from [a json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#basic-usage)

Comment: Just to give you a few keywords, this is called (de-)serialisation. Further, stick to a known metaformat, like e.g. YAML, JSON or XML. Especially the first is pretty good for config files, because it also supports comments. Inventing your own format is typically a waste of time, although it can a good learning experience.

Comment: How about JSon format as config file and some JSon library, for example [nlohmann json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). Final code will short and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooner or later, you would need to specify the actual types because [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is a typed language.

But if your problem is to avoid the branching based on the type (hence the reason why you want to use an `std::map`), **what you can do is to read the data as `std::string`s** and defer the proper conversion to another function (ideally via a contructor of `InpData`, but you can also do it via a "free function" which returns an `InpData` if you prefer).

For example, you could define your data structure like:

```
// Data structure
struct InpData
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int age;
    double score;

    // Create an InpData from an std::map
    InpData(const std::map<std::string, std::string> & dmap) : name(dmap.at("name")),
                                                               age(std::stoul(dmap.at("age"))),
                                                               score(std::stod(dmap.at("score")))
    {}
};
```

Then you just have to read the data into an `std::map<std::string, std::string>` and the job is done.
Such a function may be defined as follows:

```
// Function to read data into an std::map
std::map<std::string, std::string> read_data(std::istream & is)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> data;

    std::string line, key, val;
    while(std::getline(is, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if(std::getline(iss, key, '=') && std::getline(iss, val, '\n'))
            data[key] = val;
    }

    return data;
}
```

And it could then be used like below:

```
int main()
{
    // Input data stream (for the example)
    std::istringstream dstream("name=Ben\nage=21\nscore=4.65");
    
    // Create an InpData object from the returned std::map of the read_data() function
    InpData d(read_data(dstream));

    // Display (for validation)
    std::cout << d.name << " - " << d.age << " - " << d.score << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live example here](https://godbolt.org/z/dvWY7bhse)</kbd>